# Realizar calculo de porcentagem Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde pessoal.

Tenho um campo com valor readonly .
Esse campo já em preenchido com dado de meu banco.

Tenho um outro campo, onde irei digitar o valor da porcentagem.

Como faço para o valor do resultado ser apresentado no outro campo?

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor" value="80.00" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="percentual">Percentual (%)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual" id="percentual" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00%">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="resultado">Resultado</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resultado" id="resultado" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="R$ 0.00">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim sem jquery:

```js
document.getElementById('percentual').onkeyup = function() {
  var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor').value);
  document.getElementById('resultado').value = valor * (parseFloat(this.value)/100);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">                           
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="80.00" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="percentual">Percentual (%)</label>                                
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual" id="percentual" title="Informe o percentual"  size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00%"  >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="resultado">Resultado</label>                                
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resultado" id="resultado" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="R$ 0.00"  >
  </div>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente como eu preciso. Obrigada @Junior

Comment: @MarciaPereiraReis se essa resposta te ajudou, marque ela como solução no lado esquerdo dela, para que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas!

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#percentual").on('input',function() {
 var Valor = $("#valor").val();
  var Porcentagem = $("#percentual").val();
  var resultado = (Valor * Porcentagem) / 100;
  $("#resultado").val(resultado)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="80.00" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="percentual">Percentual (%)</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual" id="percentual" title="Informe o percentual"  size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00%"  >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="resultado">Resultado</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resultado" id="resultado" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="R$ 0.00"  >
                                    </div>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: Gabriel, sugestões: Usa letra grande em variáveis que são instâncias, e usa um conversor de tipo string para numero.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo assim

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#percentual").change(function(){
      var valor = $("#valor").val();
      $("#resultado").val(valor * (parseInt($(this).val())/100));
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor"  value="80.00" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00" readonly >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="percentual">Percentual (%)</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual" id="percentual" title="Informe o percentual"  size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00%"  >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="resultado">Resultado</label>                                
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resultado" id="resultado" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="R$ 0.00"  >
                                    </div>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: meu exemplo estava como 1 = 100% fiz alteração igual do calculo com exemplo na resposta do [@JuniorNunes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57573/juniornunes)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#percent").change(function() {
  if (parseFloat($(this).val()) <= 100) {
    var porcentagem = (parseFloat($("#valor").val()) * parseFloat($(this).val())) / 100;
    $("#resultado").val(porcentagem);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="valor">Valor (R$)</label>
    <input id="valor" type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" id="valor" value="80.00" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="percentual">Percentual (%)</label>
    <input id="percent" type="text" class="form-control" name="percentual" id="percentual" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00%">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="resultado">Resultado</label>
    <input id="resultado" type="text" class="form-control" name="resultado" id="resultado" title="Informe o percentual" size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="R$ 0.00">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por exemplo, eu acho que um problema é que se você digita um valor acima de 100%, ex: 160%. Ele vai dá um valor nada a ver.

Comment: Obrigado @MauroAlexandre, coloquei uma condição para esse caso.